# When will bringing a position charge does not results in increase in electric field?

Tags: electrostatics

A point charge is brought inside an electric field. The electric field at a nearby point-

(a) will increase if the charge is positive.

(b) will decrease if the charge is negative.

(c) may increase if the charge is positive.

(d) may decrease if the charge is negative.

Answer is (c) and (d) but I think it should be (a) and (b). 
So my question is- 
When will bringing a position charge does not results in increase in electric field?

Original question is taken from HC Verma concept of physics part 2 page number 120 question 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total electric field will certainly change at all points, but the trick is that it can increase or decrease at a chosen point. A positive charge does not increase electric field at all points but decreases it at some points, like for example where the original electric field has opposite direction to the field of the point charge. So a positive charge will increase the field at some points and decrease at some other points and the same applies for negative charge.